# include file and https stops my css from working

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Okay, so I have a really odd problem... I have this line at the top of my page, because I want to get the latest wordpress blog post (which is fine, the post comes back);

```
<?php
    require('./blog/wp-load.php');
?>
```

But then whenever I visit a page on my website that has https:// in the url it seems to stop my css file from working would anyone be able to help? thanks

Comment: transfer css file via SSL as well. not only html (depends on browser)

Answer (score 1):

in wordpress its always best to use the right api method:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url

```
<?php
     $url = site_url();
     require($url. /blog/wp-load.php');
?>
```

> The site_url template tag retrieves the site url for the current site (where the WordPress core files reside) with the appropriate protocol, 'https' if is_ssl() and 'http' otherwise. If scheme is 'http' or 'https', is_ssl() is overridden. Use this to get the "wordpress address" as defined in general settings. Use home_url() to get the "site address" as defined in general settings.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function site_url() in /home/cleverca/public_html/inc/header.php on line 2

that's what it comes up with

Comment: where is this file you have the require() in? is it in the root of your server or is it in your theme directory?

Comment: It's in a folder called 'inc'

Comment: the wp-load.php is in the wordpress files root.. meaning its In the first level of your wordpress directory.. where are the files for your wordpress?

Comment: Well... the site isn't a proper wordpress website, it's a website all coded by me... but with a wordpress blog, the blog is in a folder called blog and that folder is at the root, and so is the inc... hence the ./blog/wp-load.php which works, it gets the file but and it does show the wordpress post, but what I don't get is why it stops my css working over SSL